# How does type inference differ between constant and non-constant global variables?

Tags: julia

From the Julia [docs on array comprehensions](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/arrays/#comprehensions):

> The following example computes a weighted average of the current
>   element and its left and right neighbor along a 1-d grid. :
>
> ```
> julia> const x = rand(8)
> 8-element Array{Float64,1}:
>  0.843025
>  0.869052
>  0.365105
>  0.699456
>  0.977653
>  0.994953
>  0.41084
>  0.809411
>
> julia> [ 0.25*x[i-1] + 0.5*x[i] + 0.25*x[i+1] for i=2:length(x)-1 ]
> 6-element Array{Float64,1}:
>  0.736559
>  0.57468
>  0.685417
>  0.912429
>  0.8446
>  0.656511
> ```
>
> *Note*
>
> *In the above example, `x` is declared as constant because type inference
>   in Julia does not work as well on non-constant global variables.*
>
> The resulting array type is inferred from the expression; in order to
>   control the type explicitly, the type can be prepended to the
>   comprehension. For example, in the above example we could have avoided
>   declaring x as constant, and ensured that the result is of type
>   Float64 by writing:
>
> ```
> Float64[ 0.25*x[i-1] + 0.5*x[i] + 0.25*x[i+1] for i=2:length(x)-1 ]
> ```

What does the note near the end mean? That is, how does type inference differ between constant and non-constant global variables?

Comment: If you take out the `const`, you end up with a 6-element array of `Any`, not `Float64`. Note that if you move the code inside a function, you _do_ get an array of `Float64` even without the `const`. However, I don't know enough about type inference behavior to answer your question fully.

Comment: Reference: issue [#8870](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8870)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem is that if `x` is not declared as a `const`, then Julia has no idea if the type of that variable will ever change (because it never falls out of scope as a global). For this reason, Julia would need to assume `x` is of type `Any`.

If `x` is declared as a `const`, however, Julia can safely assume that its type will not change, and Julia can make optimizations based on that information.

Note that if you do not declare `x` as a const, then the returned type from the list comprehension will be `Array{Any,1}`